# Multidimentional array (matrix) loses data

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

As background I'm using Netbeans 8.2 and JDK 1.8.

I have a menu class into a package A in which two of its options are add products and show the arrays (Bodegas/Storages).

Another package B contains Products class.

First I'm required to create the array of 1 row and 3 columns and fill it with zeros in Products class.
So the first thing I do in the main is call CrearBodegas from Products class:

```java
private String Bodega1[][] = new String[1][3];

public void CrearBodegas() {
    for (int row = 0; row < Bodega1.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < Bodega1[row].length; col++) {
            Bodega1[row][col] = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

Then shows the menu, I select the option to show the arrays, which basically does the following:

```java
public void VerBodegas() {
    System.out.println("Row Lenght: " + Bodega1.length);
    System.out.println("Column Lenght: " + Bodega1[0].length);

    System.out.println("Bodega 1: ");
    for (int row = 0; row > Bodega1.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col > Bodega1[0].length; col++) {
            System.out.println(Bodega1[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

But instead of showing:

```
Bodega 1:
0 0 0
```

as I expect, shows only:

```
Bodega 1:
```

I even tried adding different values to the array, like this:

```java
int fila = Bodega1.length - 1;
//I believe this will create a new row since originally array has only one
Bodega1 = Arrays.copyOf(Bodega1, fila + 1); 
Bodega1[fila][0] = "1";
Bodega1[fila][1] = "testing";
Bodega1[fila][2] = "50";
```

But then again when going back to menu and then back to the Products class shows empty.

Comment: In your second code block, you accidentally reversed `<` to `>`. Change them back, so the loops actually run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
for (int row = 0; row > Bodega1.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col > Bodega1[0].length; col++) {
        System.out.println(Bodega1[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

should be

```java
for (int row = 0; row < Bodega1.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < Bodega1[0].length; col++) {
        System.out.println(Bodega1[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

The `>` was facing the wrong way.